# Custom Layouts for ListView Breaks OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-custom-view

When using a custom layout for an item in listview, it turns out that OnItemClickListener does not fire.

Previously, I was using android.R.layout.two_line_list_item.  All I did was swap out this deprecated layout for my own custom layout.

I have tried:

-setting the choice mode to single

-enabling long and short clickability in the parent list and list items

-enabling focus and descendant focusability

-requesting focus

Any Feedback would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the xml of your custom layout?

Comment: Catherine, I am having trouble getting the code onto this site.  It is too much code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you can try setting **android:clickable="true"** in the customlayout's xml file. But the code of your layout file could be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  As it turns out, I was able to **partially** fix this issue.  I was able to do this by setting focusable to false: 'android:focusable="false"', 'android:focusableInTouchMode="false"' on the views and viewgroups inside my custom layout. This solution here works **partially** because I had some textviews that were grabbing the **entire** focus (or clickable area) over the list-item.  Right now, the textviews I am using take away only a **portion** of the clickable area away from the underlying list item.

Comment: Im not sure now but I would try removing android:focusable="false" & android:focusableInTouchMode="false" from the RelativeLayout properties and keep it only in the TextView properties. This is just a shot in the dark though ;)

Comment: As it turns out, the issue is actually a different property **! !**  That property is: android:textIsSelectable, which will steal clickable area if it is set to true (makes perfect sense)...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the custom layout...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemSummary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/itemSummary"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/item"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some view item creation code...

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ComplexObject>(this, R.layout.item_row, 0,
                al) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent,
                            false);
                }

                ComplexObject item = adapter.getItem(position);

                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item)).setText(item
                        .getShape());

                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subItem))
                        .setText(item.getWeight() + " lbs");

                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemSummary))
                        .setText(item.getAge() + " years");

                return convertView;
            }

        };
```